# JSON Reformatting - Patching Unique Keys

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

Doing an Android app. Created the server-side code to return a JSON code like this one:

```
{
  "msg": "",

  "patients": {
    "PAT_CONST": {
      "name": "Anna",
      "id": "5"
    },
    "PAT_CONST": {
      "name": "John",
      "id": "6"
    },
    "PAT_CONST": {
      "name": "Helen",
      "id": "7"
    }
  },

  "ok": true
}
```

However, I think it is illegal (or not advisable) to have Keys with the same name ("PAT_CONST" in this case) inside the main JSONObject.

How can I rewrite the above JSON so that I can have a structured JSON with multiple patients, each of them having their own "name" and "id" keys? Maybe using an Array, and how would you do it to optimize the efficiency of the parsing task carried out in the client-side?

Comment: You actually just remove the `PAT_CONST` just leaving `"patients": [ {"name": "John", "id": "6" }]`, thus them being objects themselves. You cannot have two same name keys.

Comment: Thanks @Rcls, useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the patients as an array of key value pairs:

"patients": [ {
      "name": "Anna",
      "id": "5"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "id": "6"
    },
    {
      "name": "Helen",
      "id": "7"
    }]

Comment: Thanks, really useful. There are so many different ways to do things that sometimes I struggle at trying to find the optimal, simplest one.